# JQuery datatables showing plain HTML page while loading

Tags: jquery, datatables

Can someone please help me with this code? I'm facing problem i.e plain html page showing up  in the beginning. I noticed that with smaller query like 100 records, it works fine but with larger queries like 8000. It shows entire table as plain html table while loading in the beginning and then works normally.

```
        $(document).ready( function () {
            var oTable = $('#datatables').dataTable( {
                "bJQueryUI": true,
                "sScrollY": "300px",
                "sScrollX": "100%",
                "sScrollXInner": "150%",
                "bScrollCollapse": true,
                "bPaginate": true,
                "aaSorting":[[0, "asc"]],
                "sPaginationType":"full_numbers",
            });
            new FixedColumns( oTable );
        });
```

Comment: Maybe try hiding the table's content until it fully loaded?

Comment: That's why Ajax was created.  You'll want to load the values using the Ajax option so that it queries a remote page where the records are served from.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, set your table to `hidden` by default:

```
<table id="#datatables" hidden>
```

Then include the `initComplete` callback in the `$().DataTable()` constructor. This will run only after all of the data has been loaded, so you can then set your table to `$().show()`:

```
$('#datatables').dataTable( {
  "initComplete": function(settings, json) {
     $('#datatables').show();
     }
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove any data in your HTML file and leave it empty.  This way your page loads right away.  The Ajax source will display a nice loading graphic while the data is being loaded into the page.

Below is the configuration for the plugin to use the Ajax source option.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#datatables').dataTable( {
        "bProcessing": true,
        "sAjaxSource": 'arrays.txt'
    } );
} );
```

Below is served from the arrays.txt where your data is served as a static file or perhaps you have server logic to create your data:
**arrays.txt**

```
{
  "aaData": [
    [
      "Trident",
      "Internet Explorer 4.0",
      "Win 95+",
      "4",
      "X"
    ],
    [
      "Trident",
      "Internet Explorer 5.0",
      "Win 95+",
      "5",
      "C"
    ],
    [
      "Trident",
      "Internet Explorer 5.5",
      "Win 95+",
      "5.5",
      "A"
    ]
}
```